# in check out page check zip code is valid or not?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, zipcode

i m using magento 1.9 
i need to create zip code availability  check in check out page for particular order.particular product wise check zip code and if zip code is not valid then highlight zip code text box.
so please help me.

Comment: what do you mean by particular order?

Comment: means user wise check this filed.if guest can enter zip code then check if user can login and add new address that time check zip code is valid or not so please help us..

Comment: try https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shipping-restriction.html